# Developing algortihm/model to identify thin linear features in aerial imagery

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

I am exploring the possibility of identifying fencelines from NAIP aerial imagery (GSD = 0.6m). I have tried some basic processing in OpenCV using canny edge detection that was detailed in a question [to the OpenCV forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/198247/detect-fence-lines-from-aerial-imagery/).

Here's what time imagery looks like. The right shows the fenceline mask.
[image]

The next approach seems to be to try a CNN. I'm thinking I'll try implementing the unet architecture. I'm looking for suggestions, including alternative approaches, as well as comments on whether this is a fool's errand.

For training, my initial plan is to convert my vector line features into a 2-pixel wide raster mask. <s>Thoughts?</s>

For clarity: Does implementing the unet architecture seem like a good first step to approach this problem? Is my masking approach reasonable?

Comment: "Thoughts?" is too broad a question to be practically answered. The way to determine if a particular model works for some problem is to conduct an experiment. Once you've reviewed the results, you can make model adjustments to improve the results. This OODA loop is the core task in machine learning. You may find it helpful to review http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/ and https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but I agree with the comment above -- "thoughts?" is too broad.

Comment: Sycorax: I'm asking if my approach using unet seems reasonable. I show my initial experiment in the link to the OpenCV forum post above. I'm looking for feedback if using the unet architecture with my line masking seems like a good approach. Why troll?